# Mat table column header alignment

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

My `mat-table` columns doesn't have alignment correct.

**Css:**

```
mat-header-cell, mat-cell {
  justify-content: center;
}

table{
  width: 100%;
}
 
.cdk-column-email {
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  white-space: unset !important;
  flex: 0 0 15% !important;
  width: 15% !important;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  word-break: break-word;

  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>S.No</b></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item; let i = index">
         {{ (paginatorRef.pageIndex * paginatorRef.pageSize) + (i + 1) }}
      </td>
     </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let colIndex = index" [cdkColumnDef]="column.columnDef" class="row-color">
 
      <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > <b>{{ column.header }}</b></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"  [ngClass]="{ 'selected': row === selectedRow }">{{ column.cell(row) }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

       <ng-container cdkColumnDef="update">
          <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> <b>Update</b> </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let element">       
                <mat-icon class="mat-18" (click)="Editdata(element)">edit</mat-icon>               
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
     
        <ng-container cdkColumnDef="delete">
            <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> <b>Delete</b> </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let element">                
                  <mat-icon class="mat-18" (click)="openDialog(element.id)">delete</mat-icon>                  
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>   

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'row-color': !row.active}"></mat-row>             
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator #paginatorRef pageSize="15" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

**Output:**
[image]

The alignment i get isn't same for all columns and this is the output when I `justify-content` to center. If not,

[image]

What should i do to make it look good?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.mat-header-cell {
    justify-content: center;
}
```

or this:

```
.mat-header-cell {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to do it only for certain columns but not all ?

Comment: @MarcRoussel sure, for certain column you can use `mat-column-{name-of-your-column}` class. for example`.mat-column-email { flex: 2; }`